# KeychainWrapper causing unexpected behaviour

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui, keychain

I am using the [KeychainWrapper](https://github.com/puretears/KeychainWrapper) in my Swift app and `KeychainWrapper.standard.bool(forKey: "isUserInSub")` is causing a bug.

The line  `@State var isUserDeactive: Bool = KeychainWrapper.standard.bool(forKey: "isUserInSub") == true ? false : true` causes a completely irrelevant view to pop-up (and not be able to be dismissed). I also tried initializing the variable as false and assigning it the keychain value .onAppear, but it causes the same behaviour. I am in my main content view, if that makes a difference.

The key value is retrieved and assigned correctly, no bugs there. It is also being retrieved and used in other components successfully without a bug.

Here is the code of the view, I am using the bool to render a screen, but the `isUserDeactive = KeychainWrapper.standard.bool(forKey: "isUserInSub")  == true ? false : true`  causes the bug

```
struct ContentView: View {
    let appDelegate = UIApplication.shared.delegate as? AppDelegate
    let loadingView = LoadingUI.shared
    @EnvironmentObject var appSettings: AppSettings
    
    @State var isUserDeactive: Bool = false
    
    var body: some View {

        ZStack {
            Group {
                if showIntroScreen {
                IntroScreenAbo()
                } else {
                   CustomTabBarContainerView(content: {
                        HomeView()
                        Top100View)

                       if isUserDeactive {
                           AboView()
                       } else {
                           MakerView()

                        MoreView()
                    })
                    .background(Color("HeaderBarHome_background"))
.....

        .onAppear {

            isUserDeactive = KeychainWrapper.standard.bool(forKey: "isUserInSub")  == true ? false : true

        }
```

Comment: *I am using the KeychainWrapper…*. What KeychainWrapper? And the other code could be helpful, too.

Comment: You could also simplify your code to`var isUserDeactive = !KeychainWrapper.standard.bool(forKey: "isUserInSub")`

Answer (score 0):

I solved it, the issue was that KeychainWrapper.standard.bool(forKey: "isUserInSub") returns a conditional Bool (Value of optional type 'Bool?' must be unwrapped to a value of type 'Bool'). I still don't know how it managed to render a random view, instead of giving a warning/error, but adding a `?? true` solved the issue.